# Flutter, Find location using Geolocator package

Tags: flutter, location

How I can find my location using Geolocator package in Flutter app??

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

Position position = await Geolocator.getLastKnownPosition();
```

[Documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator)